# CURL not sending number values in post fields xml, Characters work fine, but not numbers

Tags: wordpress, curl, numbers, httprequest

This is on wordpress.

If the 
username, password and reference all start with a letter then the request and response work fine.

But if the username, password or reference are a number then it does not seem to be sending.

On postman it works fine.

I tried to put it like a variable

```
$data = "body xml"
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
```

This did not work, But I also was not sure how I would get $user and $pass in there anyway.

```
$username = $current_user->first_name;
$password = $current_user->last_name;


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  CURLOPT_URL => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<root>\r\n  <user>" .$username. "</user>\r\n  <pass>" .$password. "</pass>\r\n  <reference>12345</reference>\r\n</root>\r\n",

  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Type: application/xml",
    "Host: xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Postman-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-length: 107"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "There are no orders to show on this account ";
} else {
```

results go here in a table etc

So if the username was Bob, Password was mypass and reference was ABC123 then it will work fine

But

If the username was Sid, Password 1234 and reference ABC444 then this wont work

If username was Alice Password mypass22 and reference 22 then this wont work

It seems to strip out the numbers from  This

```
<root>\r\n  <user>" .$username. "</user>\r\n  <pass>" .$password. "</pass>\r\n  <reference>12345</reference>\r\n</root>\r\n
```

I have echo'd $username and $password and in an echo on the page they work fine, so my guess is, its the POSTFIELDS in the Curl thats stripping numbers? or just not sending them?

---

edit

Tried changing

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<root>\r\n  <user>" .$username. "</user>\r\n  <pass>" .$password. "</pass>\r\n  <reference>12345</reference>\r\n</root>\r\n",
```

to

```
 $input_xml = '<root>
      <user>sid</user>
      <pass>Mypass</pass>
      <reference>12345</reference>
    </root>';

 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $input_xml,
```

But also Didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why this happens (it should be debugged), but you can easily stringify those variables - that will work for both numbers and strings.

Usage: (string)$username instead of $username

But, generally, you need to use correct php array as a value of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Like this:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
'user'=>$username, 
'pass'=>$password,
'reference'=>$reference
),
```

By this way receiver side would get direct $_POST["user"] like data, not any XML that should be parsed.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for response. Could you give me a clear example of what (string) means and how to use it please

Comment: Just replace $username with (string)$username in your given code. Here:   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<root>\r\n  <user>" .$username. "</user>\r\n  <pass>" .$password. "</pass>\r\n  <reference>12345</reference>\r\n</root>\r\n",

Comment: <root>\r\n  <user>" .(string)$username. "</user>\r\n  <pass>" .(string)$password. "</pass>\r\n  <reference>12345</reference>\r\n</root>\r\n 
I did this, But still does not work.

Comment: if it doesn't help either, try to use correct post data then. i am adding correct data to my answer

Comment: Unfortunately the place the request is sent to will only accept XML. I am really stuck on this.

Comment: ok. are you sure that it fails to send? may be it is XML receiver side fails to parse the given data? Because you can put anything to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS data, it will not validate nor reject it - it will just send it.  So i think you may try to inspect receiver side. For example may be it is because receiver side rejects to process too short passwords?

Comment: This was it! It was the way they were receiving it. They were rejecting the number strings. So we simply added # in front of the numbers and then there side they removed the # and ran the xml. Thank you